# Symfony unable to update the linked ManyToOne object on delete

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities `user` and `college` and they have a bidirectional relationship
This is my `User.orm.yml`

```
manyToOne:
    college:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\College
        inversedBy: user
```

This is my College.orm.yml

```
oneToMany:
    user:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\User
        mappedBy: college
```

All I want to do is, when I delete a college object from database the `college_id` in `user` table should become `null` rather than deleting the linked `User` objects

I have tried the following solution but it seems to be deleting the linked object

```
    joinColumn:
        onDelete: CASCADE
```

and if i use

```
cascade: [detach]
```

I get the error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Any push in right direction will be really appreciated.

Comment: Try this : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal

Answer (score 0):

If you do cascade detach, doctrine detach the linked elements of its objects managed. It means it is not deleted in any way, it just that doctrine does not "see" the object anymore. But your SQL database still watch about its integrity! that's why the error is thrown by SQL

you just have to put the column nullable.
I don't use yml mapping , but it should be the equivalent of `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="college_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)`